# How can I debug BLAS/LAPACK error in mgcv::gam function

Tags: r, lapack, blas, gam, mgcv

In R I'm running a mgcv::gam() function with 12000 observations and using 130 parameters (mostly factors and 3 splines. I get the following error message:

Error in magic(G$y, G$X, msp, G$S, G$off, L = G$L, lsp0 = G$lsp0, G$rank, :
BLAS/LAPACK routine 'DLASCLMOIEDDLASRTDSP' gave error code -4

I run this function 100 times with everything from 8000 to 100000 observations and it runs fine, except in one instance. There are no NAs.

I've tried to extract the model matrix from the formula, but for gam's this seems to require a model object, which I can't get because of the error.
I'm thinking this might be a collinearity issue, but I don't know how to check without a model matrix.

Comment: there is some **possibly** related discussion here https://github.com/bwlewis/irlba/issues/14 . Can you give details of your system/linear algebra libraries? Try switching BLAS versions?

Comment: If you're very patient, you may be able to debug/step through the code until just before the failure point, then save the relevant objects (with `save()` or `saveRDS()` so that you can inspect them.